# Account balance of more than 1000 over x days consecutively

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Firstly, i have a transaction database with the following field. The requirement is to alert the admin of a user if the user holds usd 1000 in balance consecutively for more than 30 days.

TransactionID
TransactionType - deposit, withdrawal, transfer
TransactionFromUserID
TransactionToUserID
TransactionValueUsd
TransactionDateTime

Note: 
- Currently i only have this table and do not have another table to update the balance. The balance is calculated on the fly.

- If one of the days is not more than 1000 usd it is needed to be recalculate again
- Need not worries about performance issue. Just need a general idea on how should i design another table to hold the value and maybe a trigger to solve this issue.

eg:
2019-01-01: deposit 500 usd 
2019-02-01: deposit 2000 usd - balance 2500 usd, start count from here
2019-02-10: withdraw 2500 usd - balance 500, reset date
2019-02-15: deposit 2000 usd - balance 2500 - start exceed date again here
2019-04-15: withdraw 1000 usd - balance 1500 - flag here and reset last exceed date

Comment: Wouldn't 2/10 have a balance of zero?   Also, it is best if you present your sample data and desired results (missing) as a table and not a narrative.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear, but I think this query is close enough to the answer:

```
select
  *
from (
  select
    transactiontouserid,
    transactiondatetime,
    sum(case when balance < 1000 then 1 else 0 end) 
    over(
      partition by transactiontouserid 
      order by transactiondatetime
      range between interval '30' day preceding and current row
    ) as disqualify_points
  from (
    select
      transactiontouserid,
      transactiondatetime,
      sum(case when transactiontype = 'deposit' then 1 else -1 end 
          * transactionvalueusd) 
      over(
        partition by transactiontouserid 
        order by transactiondatetime
      ) as balance
    from t -- your table name
  ) x
) y
where disqualify_points = 0
```